# Followup after a phone interview?

Tags: interviewing, communication, hiring-process

I had a short phone interview with the head of a small company this morning, it was more of a "see-who-this-person-is" type of call prior to meeting in person.
The call ended with us agreeing to meet as early as tomorrow morning for a proper face to face interview. He said he would forward me the office address via email.

A few hours went by and I have not received any email.
My gut feeling says I may have said something he didn't like during the phone call, but maybe he simply forgot?
The interview is tomorrow and I'm not sure on how to act right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most managers have a very, very, packed schedule.

He agreed to the meeting. Don't worry about it, yet.

Chances are that he simply forgot or it's on his to do list for today.

If he he hasn't contacted you within the close-end of his office hours just give him a call back and tell him that you didn't receive an email but you'd like to know where and when the meeting is due.

Comment: I wouldn't wait until 9 p.m., I'd be sure to call before the close of business.  Even if you have the manager's cell phone, he probably does not want to get a business call on his cell in the evening.

Comment: True, I changed the answer accordingly. Some managers do, however, work from home during the evening so that's why I mentioned the time.

Answer (score 3):

> A few hours went by and I'm not receiving any mail. My gut feeling
>   says I may have said something he didn't like during the phone call,
>   but maybe he simply forgot? The interview is tomorrow, I'm not sure on
>   how to act right now.

If you actually said something he didn't like, he most likely wouldn't have agreed to meet you tomorrow morning. It is odd though that he didn't simply tell you the office address on the phone during your call. Let's assume for a minute that he still does want to meet with you tomorrow morning.

The most likely reason is that you simply haven't waited long enough to receive the email.

Wait until an hour or so before the end of the work day. If you still haven't received the email you can do one of two things

- If you know the time of your meeting, but not the office location, then simply check the company website for the address, or call the office, speak to someone at the front desk and get the office address that way. Show up at the agreed-upon time.
- If you don't know the time of your meeting, call the company head, ask him if you are still on for the morning meeting, and get the office address that way.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about your gut feeling. You need to follow up. Since it's pretty urgent, call them and leave him a voice email if they are not picking up the phone. Remind them that you are following up because they agreed on a face to face interview the next day. Follow up  that voice mail with an email communication.

If you are not getting a response, try again the next day early in the morning. If you are not getting a response of any kind from them as the next day progresses, forget it. The ball is in their court. Whether they choose to go after it or not is their choice and prerogative.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would phone back and ask to speak to the person who interviewed you and make a casual "I just wanted to check that you had my email address correct" or perhaps "I've been having problems with emails not coming through and wanted to check I have not missed one from you" (less preferable)

Make it not about chasing but just that you are confirming they have the correct information.

If they have genuinely forgotten, it will hopefully prompt them to send the email through with the details. If there is another reason why the email has come through (as per your gut feeling), they will simply confirm the email address is correct. If you then do not receive anything, your gut was correct